# dialog is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this JavaScript code which I use for question dialog:

```
// Question Dialog
function deletedialog(button, a){      
    $("<div />", {
        text: a
    }).dialog({        
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                $(button).closest("form").find("[id$=deleterow]").click();
                $(this).dialog("close");
                button.value = "Processing...";
                button.disabled = true;                  
            }, 
            "Cancel": function(event) { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
                button.value = "Delete";
                button.disabled = false;
            } 
        }
    });         
}
```

But for some reason that I cannot find I get this error in Firebug:

```
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
```

and this row is highlighted

"Cancel": function(event) {

This problem occurs when I added this in the JSF head in order to prevent JQuery and Primefaces conflict:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
</script>
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Since you're using noConflict have you tried with `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is that the `$` symbol has been removed by using `$.noConflict()` function. Use `jQuery` instead.

### Two solutions

This basically means you should write function calls like `jQuery(this).dialog("close");` instead of `$(this).dialog("close");`.

To implement the change for the bigger piece of code, you can do it like that:

```
(function($){
    // ... old code using "$" instead of "jQuery"
})(jQuery);
```

### Solution no. 1 - multiple replacements - example

The solution with replacing `$(...)` calls with `jQuery(...)` could look like this:

```
// Question Dialog
function deletedialog(button, a){      
    jQuery("<div />", {
        text: a
    }).dialog({        
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                jQuery(button).closest("form").find("[id$=deleterow]").click();
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                button.value = "Processing...";
                button.disabled = true;                  
            }, 
            "Cancel": function(event) { 
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
                button.value = "Delete";
                button.disabled = false;
            } 
        }
    });         
}
```

### Solution no. 2 - enclosing code in anonymous function - example

This is based on the fact you can create anonymous function and pass `jQuery` to it, but assign it to the argument called `$` - which will result in `$` symbol available within the function as if it would happen before `$.noConflict()` call:

```
(function($){
    // Question Dialog
    function deletedialog(button, a){      
        $("<div />", {
            text: a
        }).dialog({        
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() { 
                    $(button).closest("form").find("[id$=deleterow]").click();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    button.value = "Processing...";
                    button.disabled = true;                  
                }, 
                "Cancel": function(event) { 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    button.value = "Delete";
                    button.disabled = false;
                } 
            }
        });         
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Would you explain your idea more deeply, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: You can also assign noConflict to a variable and use that instead of `$`, for example: `var j = jQuery.noConflict(); j.dialog(...)`

Comment: @elclanrs: That could be right, but is unnecessary - the `jQuery` variable is still accessible and for other developers it may be rather too complicated to read the code that does `j = $.noConflict();` or `j = jQuery` instead of using one of two solutions I have given (so just using `jQuery` instead or enclosing the code in self-called anonymous function that makes `$` symbol available again within the scope of the anonymous function).

Comment: @PeterPenzov: Done. Please take a look. I generally prefer using `jQuery` approach, as it does not conflict with other frameworks (such as MooTools), is clear and JS minifiers are still able to minimize it. Although for older code, as well as for some other cases, the approach with enclosing code in anonymous function call could be cleaner. I have seen examples of using eg. the following snippet: `(function(window, $, undefined){ ... })(window, jQuery);`.

Comment: The second example is a good illustration, except that I think the function "deleteddialog" would not be defined after the containing function finished executing.  It would either need to be called inside that containing function or returned in some api object.  Maybe you could add a comment (or a function call) showing where deleteddialog could be used in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Before `$.noConflict();`, `$` is equal to `jQuery`.

After `$.noConflict();`, `$` is equal to `undefined`.

This removes the `$` shortcut to `jQuery`, and that is why it is not a function anymore. You typically only use `$.noConflict();` when you add another javascript library that uses `$`. Your options are:

1. Don't use `$.noConflict();`.
2. Use `$.noConflict();` and replace every `$` with `jQuery`.
3. Use `$.noConflict();` and wrap your code with `(function($){ ... })(jQuery)`

If you need to use `$.noConflict();`, I suggest using the third one. It remaps $ to jQuery by passing jQuery as a parameter. Using the code you posted, it may look something like...

```
(function($){

    // Question Dialog
    function deletedialog(button, a){      
        $("<div />", {
            text: a
        }).dialog({        
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() { 
                    $(button).closest("form").find("[id$=deleterow]").click();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    button.value = "Processing...";
                    button.disabled = true;                  
                }, 
                "Cancel": function(event) { 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    button.value = "Delete";
                    button.disabled = false;
                } 
            }
        });         
    }

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Ryan, what is the difference between your answer (posted seconds ago) and my answer (posted 17 minutes ago), except the "_Don't use $.noConflict();_" part?

Comment: Not much. The big difference is that you answer was not posted when I started writing mine.